# How to access hard drive files of laptop with faulty ram?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, memory, bios, memory-error

I have this brand new MSI Prestige 15 that've just died after only 3 months. Cannot boot into Windows 10. Tried reinstalling Windows but after the first restart it cannot complete the installation.

I've ran Memtest86 and the RAMs are clearly faulty.
[image]

I've already started the RMA process but I'd like to access the hard-drive to backup some files.
Do I have any chance of achieving that with faulty RAM?

I've tried booting Ubuntu Live but it didn't worked.
[image]

I've also tried UltimateBootCD but couldn't boot into it as it's BIOS/UEFI-CMS only and I think this laptop is UEFI only.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**
Opening the laptop is not an option as it will void the warranty.

Comment: Contact the people who are going to repair it and ask them if it would be OK to open it to get your data. They may be completely happy for you to do that.

Comment: Regarding your edit, RAM and disks in laptops are removable and upgradeable without voiding the warranty. If in doubt contact the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

The harddisk is usually one of the easier components of a laptop to extract and replace.

The ram is usually too, so you could see if the laptop has 2 ram sticks and remove one and test like that, then the other. If there's just one ram stick, this is not possible.

If you can't get it to work by removing ram, then you can extract the harddisk and use a 2nd computer to perform the backup.

Search the internet with the brand and model number on how to replace the harddisk. These instructions will tell you how you can get the harddisk out of the laptop. You can then place the harddisk into another computer and copy the files you want to keep.

Comment: The laptop is under warranty, I'm sending it to RMA. I just need to see if I can access the hard-drive to backup some files in case they format everything as they usually do. I can't open the laptop without breaking the warranty.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Linux to avoid bad RAM sectors. It's a bit complicated, but there's a guide on our sister site: [How to blacklist a correct bad RAM sector according to MemTest86+ error indication?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/75059/53467)

Alternatively, you can remove the drive from the laptop and use a USB adapter to access the files. It's probably a M.2 drive with a SATA or NVMe connection. You'll need an adapter that matches the drive type. Googling the model number from the label on the drive may point you in the right direction.

Or you can just move the drive to another laptop or PC. That one will also have to support the correct M.2 connection type.

Comment: I guess I should have clarified that I cannot open the laptop as it's under warranty and I'm sending it for RMA. I just needed a way to access the hard-drive without opening the laptop.

Comment: You can remove or replace the RAM _and drive_ without voiding the warranty. Also the first method doesn't involve opening the laptop.